# how can i work on this problem related to 2d coordinates of a polyline

Tags: python, polyline

I have a string input of coordinates of poly-line:

```
 (1,2)(2,3)(4,5)(8,9)
```

I have function :-

```
def distance(p1,p2):
```

How can I send the value `(1,2)` and `(2,3)` to `p1` and `p2` and so on and calculate distance between each points?

Comment: Is your question how to use a function or is it how to calculate distance between points?

Comment: my question is how can I store the user input and pass it to the function parameter. Basically which data type to store and retrieve data?

Comment: Check the answer below and vote/mark accepted if it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You gather the input (which is a string):

```py
in_coord = input('Please enter coordinates in format "x y x y": ')
```

Then convert the input to sets:

```py
in_conv = [int(i) for i in in_coord if i != ' ']
p_list = []
for e in range(0, len(in_conv), 2):
    p_list.append((in_conv[e], in_conv[e+1]))
```

Now send them to your function:

```py
def distance(p1, p2):
    print(f'Result of {p1} and {p2}')

for i in range(0, len(p_list), 2):
    distance(p_list[i], p_list[i+1])
```

So in practice it looks like this:

```py
>>> in_coord = input('Please enter coordinates in format "x y x y": ')
Please enter coordinates in format "x y x y": 1 2 2 3 4 5 8 9
>>> in_conv = [int(i) for i in in_coord if i != ' ']
>>> p_list = []
>>> for e in range(0, len(in_conv), 2):
...     p_list.append((in_conv[e], in_conv[e+1]))
... 
>>> def distance(p1, p2):
...     print(f'Result of {p1} and {p2}')
... 
>>> for i in range(0, len(p_list), 2):
...     distance(p_list[i], p_list[i+1])
... 
Result of (1, 2) and (2, 3)
Result of (4, 5) and (8, 9)
```

---

If you want to take your original string, replace this for generating p_list:

```py
x = '(1,2)(2,3)(4,5)(8,9)'
p_list = []
for i in x:
    try:
        p_list.append(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

As your input is a string, you have to convert it into a tuple of int (or float) and call your function. The `combinations` function gives you all the combinations between the given point.

```py
from itertools import combinations

def distance(p1, p2):
    return (p1[0] - p2[0]) ** 2 + (p1[1] - p2[1])

input_as_string = '(1,2)(2,3)(4,5)(8,9)'

string_coordinates = input_as_string.replace(')(', ':').replace('(', '').replace(')', '').split(':')
for string_p1, string_p2 in combinations(string_coordinates, 2):
    p1 = list(map(float, string_p1.split(',')))
    p2 = list(map(float, string_p2.split(',')))
    print(distance(p1, p2))
```

I write a small function for `distance` for my test but this has to be replaced with yours.